# What is the difference between centerCrop and optionalCenterCrop in Glide?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am building an Android application in which I would like to display images using *Glide*.

I am able to find the method called `centerCrop` and `optionalCenterCrop` as below

```
Glide.with(imageView.context)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .placeholder(placeHolder)
     .optionalCenterCrop()
     .into(imageView)
```

I am **not able to see any changes** in the way the image displayed with the above implementation but the below implementation brings some notable change in the imageView.

```
Glide.with(imageView.context)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .placeholder(placeHolder)
     .centerCrop()
     .into(imageView)
```

I would like to understand what is the impact when using `optionalCenterCrop()` rather than `centerCrop()`

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `optionalCenterCrop()` & `centerCrop()` is that the `optionalCenterCrop()` applies the centerCrop to all default types and just ignores unknown types while `centerCrop()` method throws an exception if an unknown Type is used.

Basically the difference is `optionalCenterCrop()` does not throw Exception on unknown Types while `centerCrop()` throws an exception which should be handled by you.

Comment: I am little not sure about the unknown types. Can you please help me understand them?. I know the few: fitXY, fitCenter, centerInside etc.

Comment: No. The 'type' refers to the resource type of the load operation i.e Bitmap, drawable etc.